# Grails JSON renderer not exposing model for Interceptor

Tags: grails, view, json-view

I want to use the `model` field in an `Interceptor` for a JSON REST response.

The controller method responds with the domain object:

```
def show(String id) {
    respond User.get(id)
}
```

The JSON view uses `JsonViewJsonRenderer` which extends `DefaultViewRenderer`, which directly calls

```
  view.render(model, request, response)
```

and doesn't to expose a `ModelAndView` instance.  Other renderers e.g. `DefaultHtmlRenderer`, expose the model via:

```
 applyModel(context, object)
```

Is there a way to get the model field to be filled out when responding with a JSON response?   Do I need to build my own subclass of `DefaultHtmlRenderer` that sets the `ModelAndView`?

As a workaround, I could create a `ModelAndView` for each response, but this seems to not be in the ease-of-use spirit of Grails:

```
def show(String id) {
    respond new ModelAndView('user/show', User.get(id))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the model field to be filled out when responding
> with a JSON response?

Yes.  There is a `model` property available in all interceptors.  Typically this would be accessed in the `after()` method of an interceptor.

> Do I need to build my own subclass of DefaultHtmlRenderer that sets
> the ModelAndView?

No.

Comment: Sounds like this is a bug in `views-json` / `JsonViewJsonRenderer` then, because the model is `null` in the `after()` method.  I'll create an example project to demonstrate, along with a workaround.

Comment: Example repo of issue: https://github.com/flicken/grails-json-interceptor-missing-model

Comment: Created as issue on grails-views https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues/235